# Cardinality of polynomials with real coefficients

Tags: elementary-set-theory, infinity

What is the cardinality of the set of all polynomials with real coefficients? I know the power set of $\mathbb{R}$ is "more infinite" than $\mathbb{R}$, so to speak, but I'm unsure of how to prove that there does or does not exist a surjection onto $\mathbb{R}[X]$ from $\mathbb{R}$. Is it equinumerous with the power set of $\mathbb{R}$, or something else more exotic?

Comment: The set of all polynomials with real coefficients is notated $\mathbb R[X]$, which is pretty unambiguous.

Comment: OH THANK GOD. Fixing it now.

Comment: However $\mathbb R(X)$ is the field of all rational functions of one variable over $\mathbb R$, which contains many elements that are not in $\mathbb R[X]$.

Comment: A countable union of sets with cardinality $\mathfrak{c}$ has cardinality $\mathfrak{c}$

Comment: There is a surjection of $\Bbb{R}[X]$ onto $\Bbb{R}$ (e.g., $f \mapsto f(0)$). It's the possibility of a surjection of $\Bbb{R}$ onto $\Bbb{R}[X]$ that you should be interested in and such a surjection does exist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\mathbb R[X]$ has the same cardinality as $\mathbb R$ itself.

One fairly simple way to see this is to know that there are bijections $f: \mathbb R \to \mathcal P(\mathbb N)$ and $g: \mathbb N\times\mathbb N \to \mathbb N$. Then

$$h(a_0+a_1X+\cdots a_n X^n) = \{g(p,q)\mid p\in f(a_q)\}$$
defines an *injection* $h:\mathbb R[X]\to \mathcal P(\mathbb N)$, and since there are obviously at least as many polynomials as there are real numbers, the Cantor-Bernstein theorem takes care of the rest.

Comment: How do we know there are bijections from R to the natural coefficient polynomials? I completely don't understand the function you've defined either or why it would define an injection from R[X] to R, or why or how N X N and P(N) enter into it. Would you please explain more thoroughly?

Comment: @BreakingBioinformatics: $\mathcal P(\mathbb N)$ is the _power set_ of $\mathbb N$, that is, the set of all subsets of $\mathbb N$; it doesn't have anything to do with polynomial. It is usually one of the earliest facts taught about cardinalities that $\mathbb R$ and $\mathcal P(\mathbb N)$ have the same cardinality -- that is, that the bijection $f$ exists.

Comment: $h$ works by translating each coefficient to a subset of $\mathbb N$. Then each member of that subset is paired with the position of the coefficient, such that we can represent all of the coefficients at once as a single subset of $\mathbb N\times\mathbb N$. Finally this is squashed into a subset of $\mathbb N$ by applying the pairing function $g$ to each pair.

Comment: *facepalms* I realized it was the powerset as I was reading and thought I had corrected myself. I'm aware that N's power set has the same cardinality of R (I proved it to myself the day I posted this question actually). So essentially, you're assuming that an injective function compose a bijective function is injective?

Comment: @BreakingBioinformatics: It is quite elementary that the composition of two injective functions is injective (and a bijection is, of course, in particular injective).

Answer (score 1):

Another proof notes there are $|\Bbb R|^k=|\Bbb R|$ degree-$k$ polynomials for $k\ge0$ and one vanishing polynomial, and so there are $1+|\Bbb R|\aleph_0=1+|\Bbb R|=|\Bbb R|$ polynomials.